# While loop statement sums all but the first input?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I have a small piece of code that continuously asks the user to input a number until it receives an input that is divisible by 10 `(input % 10)` and sums all inputs however it does not add the first input

```java
import java.util.*;
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int input, sum = 0;

       System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
       input = in.nextInt();

       while (input % 10 != 0) {
           System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
           input = in.nextInt();
           sum += input;

           if (input % 10 == 0) {
               System.out.println("The total value is: " + sum);
               System.out.println("The last input was divisible by 10");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Example run

```
Enter a number: 15
Enter a number: 27
Enter a number: 45
Enter a number: 50
The total value is: 122
The last input was divisible by 10
```

The total value is 122 even though it should be 137 because it did not add the first input which is 15

Comment: Yes, because you are not using the first input outside of the while-Loop and directly overriding it inside the while-Loop ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're tossing the first line away. This seems like a perfect opportunity to use a `do-while` instead.

Also, you can move the actual printing outside the loop.

```
import java.util.*;
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int sum = 0;
       int input;

       do {
           System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
           input = in.nextInt();
           sum += input;

       } while (input % 10 != 0)

       System.out.println("The total value is: " + sum);
       System.out.println("The last input was divisible by 10");
    }
}
```

Note that this lays on the premise that you still want to add the last value to the sum even if it was divisible by 10.

If that's not what you want, you need to make the addition conditional as well.

```
import java.util.*;
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       int sum = 0;
       int input;

       do {
           System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
           input = in.nextInt();
           if (input % 10 != 0)
               sum += input;

       } while (input % 10 != 0)

       System.out.println("The total value is: " + sum);
       System.out.println("The last input was divisible by 10");
    }
}
```